# Python Searching Directory for Multiple Files, Editing Them All to Include Line

Tags: python, io

I need to search a directory for all files staring with downtime and add a line into each one.

Right now I have the following:

```
os.chdir("/misc/downtimerecords")

for file in glob.glob("downtime*"):
    fo=open("","a+")
    fo.write("Network Cause")
    fo.close()
```

How can I change this so that no matter how many files I have in the directory this will work? Currently I will get an error because of the `""` in `fo=open`. I want this to be the name of every file that begins with downtime.

Comment: `fo = open(file, "a+")` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better still:

```
stringvar = "string to append"
for filename in glob.glob("downtime*"):
    with open(filename,"a+") as fo:
        fo.write("Network Cause {}\n".format(stringvar))
```

...as `file` shadows a Python [built-in](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file)

The `with open(...) as ... :` idiom ensures that the file object gets closed even if something nasty happens (and it's neater!)

Comment: How would I edit this if I wanted to put in text, a string, then create a new line?

Comment: Added code to add a string variable and a newline to the output. If that's what you wanted, it may be better to add that requirement to your original post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the "" in `open()` with `file`. When you use a for loop to iterate over a list in python, the variable after `for` is the variable where you can access the current element of the list.